# Change name values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Been at this for a long time, and it seems so simple but I cannot get it to do what I want.

Each book has a 'getOrRequest' value that is selected using radio buttons. Every time a div is duplicated, the name value needs to be changed so that a book has its own getOrRequest value. I've finally got the duplicating down, but now renaming the correct inputs isn't cooperating.

What's really bugging me is that it works, but it's not changing the name values that I'm trying to grab. It has something to do with what parts of the array are being changed, but I can't get the values that I want, namely the last two getOrRequest names.

A working example of what I'm struggling with [here](http://ithacabooktrade.com/createPost.php).

My JS function:

```
function addAnotherPost(){

var bookInfo = document.getElementById('bookInformation');
var copyDiv = document.getElementById('addListing').cloneNode(true);

copyDiv.id = 'addListing' + idNumber;
bookInfo.appendChild(copyDiv);

var divID = 'addListing' + idNumber;
var newDiv = document.getElementById(divID);
var postType = document.getElementsByName("getOrRequest[]");

alert(postType[0].name + postType[1].name + postType[2].name + postType[3].name);

for(var i = 2; i < postType.length; i++){
   postType[i].name = 'getOrRequest' + idNumber + '[]';
}

alert("got this far" + postType.length);

idNumber++;
}
```

The relevant chunk of HTML:

```
<div id='addListing'>
<table class='aListing'>
<tr>
<td>
                <label>
                <input type='radio' name='getOrRequest[]' value='1' />
                Request</label>
                <label>
                <input type='radio' name='getOrRequest[]' value='0' />
                Offer</label>
</td>
[...]
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it correct to assume that idNumber is a global js variable (meaning it is declared outside of all functions)?

Comment: working example do not work see http://jsfiddle.net/P924s/1/

Comment: Is there a reason why they are not created with the right name in the first place?

Comment: The div 'addListing' is copied and then I want to change the name values. 'idNumber' is declared before the function in the <script> tags so yes it's global?

Comment: FINALLY GOT IT. I ended up setting the two radio buttons to the desired name manually, starting with postType[3] and then postType[2]. Something must have been up with the use of a for loop and the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting an object list for a specific name identifier:

```
var postType = document.getElementsByName("getOrRequest[]");
```

so postType is changing once you've renamed an element (Yes man that thing is inteligent)

```
    console.log(postType.length); // = 4
    postType[i].name = 'getOrRequest' + idNumber + '[]';
    console.log(postType.length); // = 3
```

so basically the for loops changes because postType.length changes.

I guess what you want to do is something like:

```
postType[0].name = 'getOrRequest' + idNumber + '[]'; //ref changed.
postType[0].name = 'getOrRequest' + idNumber + '[]';
```

however thats bad style anyways you should clone from a marked source and rename by name before you append to something, like so ( http://jsfiddle.net/bHLZA/2/ ):

```
var bookInfo = document.getElementById('bookInformation');
var copyDiv = document.getElementById('addListing').cloneNode(true);

copyDiv.id = 'addListing' + idNumber;
postType = copyDiv.getElementsByTagName('input');
postType[0].name = 'getOrRequest' + idNumber + '[]';
postType[1].name = 'getOrRequest' + idNumber + '[]';
bookInfo.appendChild(copyDiv);
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/bHLZA/

Comment: Thank you for putting it into more elegant words. I had the inkling that this was happening, but couldn't make it cooperate in the way I wanted. Read my final comment in the above answer. It's a jerry-rigged solution but hey it's a jerry-rigged website.

Comment: Could you actually elaborate or point to a source on how I could rename before appending? Would I make a hidden 'addListing' div that I would copy?